# Restrictions of measure converges to original measure?

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let X be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $(X,A,\mu)$ be a measure space. Let  $K_n$ be compact sets that exaust $X$, i.e. $X=\bigcup\limits_{n\ge 1}K_n$. I was wondering if the restriction $\mu_n:=\left.\mu\right\rvert_{K_n}$ was narrowly converging to $\mu$. By definition of narrow convergence, I have to show that $\int fd\mu_n\to \int fd\mu$ for every $f$ bounded and continuous but I am not sure if the claim is true and how to start.

Comment: weak converges (test functions are $\mathbb{C}_b(X)$ works for measures of total finite variation. In the case you re describing, I think value convergence is more appropriate (test functions are $\mathcal{C}_{00}(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu$ is an infinite measure then $\int f d\mu$ need not exist for $f$ bounded and continuous, so I will assume that $\mu$ is a  finite positive measure. I will also assume that $K_n$ increases to $X$. In this case $\int fd\mu_n=\int_{K_n} fd\mu \to \int fd\mu$ by DCT.

If $K_n$'s are not increasing the result is fasle since $K_1$ may be repeated infinitely many times in the sequence $(K_n)$.